# User is getting String length is less than 0 or not an integer. Details: errorKind in BI launch pad other users can run the report

Tags: date, crystal-reports, integer

User is getting the following error message when trying to run a report.
Error in formula Date range 1: 'Mid (totext ({?Due Date Range 1}),1 ,InStr (totext ({?Due Date Range 1}),"." )-1 )' String length is less than 0 or not an integer. Details: errorKind
Colleague can run the report with the criteria.
I can rerun her failed reports and get a success.
Have checked her preferences in BI launch pad and the date on her PC, any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: My long shot is: user did not enter a date or the windows date time formats are different on the machines (or user accounts).

Comment: Colleagues machine is configured the same for date /time and bi launch pad.  She has entered the date in the correct format when trying to run the report.  Hence I can rerun her reports successfully

Comment: Your formula is assuming that the dot '.' is the date separator? I understand that is the problem. For a test, you could remove that formula and print the parameter {?Due Date Range 1} to find out what is happening.